# Select products, that have all of the parameters in column

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, squeel

I have a `Product` model and `ProductParams`, where I store product ids, column with some additional parameters(`param`) and param type.
It will look like that:

```
id | type  | param
   |       |
1  | color | blue
1  | type  | hard
2  | color | blue
2  | type  | soft
.. | ..... | .....
```

How do I get only first product, when I call it with `params = [blue, hard]`?
For now I thought of something like `Product.joins{product_params}.where{product_params.param.in params}.uniq`, but I get 2nd as well, because it is `blue` too...

I use squeel gem, to constuct SQL queries, but answer doesn't have to be in squeel as well.

**EDIT**
I came up with solution, but it's a bit strange:

```
Product.joins{product_params}.where{product_params.param.in params}.group{id}.having{count(product_params.param) == 2}
```

But it would be great, if there was more graceful one.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question:  can you describe your situation in more detail in the question, eg with proper model names?  When you start using example names instead of the real ones it can cause a lot of confusion, so if you're going to use example model, column etc names then at least spell them all out in detail.

Comment: Well, I don't really know what to add here. I have a form, that submits params, and when they are submitted, I need to get Products, that are meeting these params.